# issue with concatenating multidimensional list with python

Tags: python, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with parsing a json file with a function. I'm trying to solve my problem for hours and I can't find a way around it :/

Here is the json source that I am parsing (I know I can remove [] on each "series_x"):

```
{
    "series_1":
    [
        {
            "x": [1,2,4,6,8],
            "y": [1,4,8,12,16]
        }
    ],
    "series_2":
    [
        {
            "x": [1,2,4,6,8],
            "y": [1,4,16,36,42]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote a function to return a specific value of x or y in Python. This function works fine.

```
import json
    def importJson(filePath):
            with open(filePath) as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                data = data['series_1'][0]['x']
                return data
        print(importJson('jasonfile.json'))
```

Now this is cool but the function will always return the same value. So this is a bit pointless. Therefore I tried to write a function that takes filePath and the multidimensional elements of the data list as arguments. Note: I want this argument to contain an undefined number of list dimensions in case I want to return all "series_1" or a specific value of "y" in it.
So I wrote this:

```
import json

def importJson(filePath, dataPath):
    with open(filePath) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        dataOut = data[dataPath[0]]
        i=1
        while i < len(dataPath):
            dataOut += [dataPath[i]]
            i += 1
        return dataOut

print(importJson('dataSource.json', list(['series_1',0,'x'])))
```

as you can imagine it doesn't work as it is not possible to concatenate multidimensional lists like this. so a[0][1] != a[0] + [1]
I tried many many things and nothing works, I feel the solution is simple I just can't get my head around it. Anyone sees something that could help?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using the pprint module to see the output at each step? `from pprint import pprint`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're talking about multi-dim arrays.  Your input doesn't have any, and I'm not sure why you want to introduce them.  Look at the structure of your input: a dict with keys like 'series_1', where each value is a list of one element that has a dict with keys like 'x' and 'y', where each value is a list of numbers.  You'll need to go through the `dataPath` to get the right thing at each level.  When you hit the end of `dataPath` (a list, presumably) then you return what you've got.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it clearly sorry for that. I want te function to take as an argument an indicator on what to return within the jsonfile. so if I just input data['series_1'], no problem it will return it. The problem is that I want this function to scale to other nodes of the Json, this is why I am using the while to "define" how many notes will be needed to parse and to build the parser such as data['series_1'][0]['x'][0]. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem in your code is that you're trying to sum things up, especially things that don't make sense to sum, like adding 'series_1' to 'x'.  I think all you need to do is something like this:

```
d = data
for i in dataPath:
    d = d[i]
return d
```

Comment: it is not really a sum in fact as the format I need for data at the end is like this data['series_1'][0]['x'], not data['series_1']+[0]+['x'].

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but your code is is summing when you say `dataOut += ...`.  If you do something like the above, I think that's what you're looking for.